# Google script not executing when file shared with anybody with link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Having a problem executing App Script when Google sheet is opened by user that is not logged in.   Spreadsheet is set to editable by anybody with link.  If user is logged in then script works as intended.

Here is my App. Script:

```
/**  A special function that runs when the spreadsheet is open */

function onOpen() {
// Display a dialog box with a title, message, input field, and "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons. The
 // user can also close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.prompt('Update Listing', 'Please enter the tournament date as mm/dd', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

 // Process the user's response.
 if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').setValue( response.getResponseText());
 } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
   Logger.log('The user didn\'t want to provide a date.');
 } else {
   Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because while the Sheet is accessible and editable by a user when not logged in, the script is only accessible/editable/runnable when the user is logged in. Unfortunately, the functions of the app-script will not be extendable to users that are not logged in.